# Create method does not add any records to my index list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to pass crud methods.
I made a Leads model, controller, view and routes.

When I submit the form of my /leads/new page if i write `post 'leads/index'`
in my route.rb file, my browser directs me to the index page where my new record does not show up.

If I skip the code above in route I get routing errors.

**Controller :**

```
   def new
     @leads = Leads.new
   end

   def create
     @leads = Leads.new(params[:id])
     if @leads.save
       redirect_to(:action => index)
     else
       render(new)
     end
    end
```

**Route:**

```
resources :leads
```

**View Index:**

```
<h1>Leads#index</h1>
<%= link_to 'Add new Leads', new_lead_path %>
<% @leads.each do |lead| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= lead.name %></td>
      <td><%= lead.familyname %></td>
      <td><%= lead.mobile %></td>
      <td><%= lead.email %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'show' , lead %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

**View New:**

```
<h1>Leads#new</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First -- Sontya is correct, your `Lead` model should be singular. This will help fix the routing issues.

Secondly, you are passing `params[:id]` in to `Leads.new`, which will make a lead with an explicitly passed `id`, rather than letting `ActiveRecord` handle that. You want to pass (I am guessing, as you dont have your `form` partial code up) `params[:lead]` instead (or whatever the form calls it).

Also, there are minor issues, like calling your single created `Lead` `@leads` (should be `@lead`) -- this shouldnt cause any issues, but it is better convention/better for readability.

Comment: i create a new project and correct the model to Lead and change the create method as below `def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end` and the method lead_param like  `def lead_params
    params.require(:lead).permit(:name,:family,:email,:mobile)
  end`  i think the problem was this calling as you mention and also the model name

Answer (score 0):

Rails says that model name should be singular and controller names should be plural. If you follow it is better for your understanding and all others understanding.